# TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 4, file "Code"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to delete specific rows containing specific string "X".

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('delete containing');
  var r = s.getRange('A:A');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='Substitution: ')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

But I am getting below error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange of null.(line 4, file "Code").

Can Anybody help me resolving this error? Thank you

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sheet name is wrong

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename): getSheetByName() "Returns null if there is no sheet with the given name." So you need to handle that, see the inserted if block:

```
function deleteRows() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getSheetByName('delete containing');
    if (s === null) {
      ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert("No worksheet of that name"); // Note: displays in the worksheet GUI, not the scripts editor.
      return false;
    }
    var r = s.getRange('A:A');
    var v = r.getValues();
    for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
      if(v[0,i]=='Substitution: ') // [sic] jshint kicking up a storm about this line!
        s.deleteRow(i+1);
  }
```

Comment: but why is this not working if the sheet with the given name exists (as I have already created google spreadsheet) and how to resolve this?

Comment: Looking at the images you provided: your **spreadsheet** name is 'delete containing', but what we can't see are the individual **worksheets** within the spreadsheet. Could you be confused about the difference between the spreadsheet and the worksheets it contains? For your code to work, there needs to be a worksheet called 'delete containing'.

Comment: I'm afraid that "not working" doesn't really help anyone help you. I suggest your read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again with a new, specific, question.